# Logging partial times in production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, performance, logging

Is it possible to just log partial times without turning on all logging with?

```
config.log_level = :debug
```

I just want to see partial times as all the others seem under control and don't want to slow down the application to get this logging.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible. You can change the log level sometimes, but you can't do it to some controller.

Comment: I am happy for all controllers to have it - it is just that I don't need the SQL and other logging. Is that possible?

Comment: yes, You can define the ActiveRecord::Base.logger.level = :info

Comment: It seems in the production.rb file, the logger is not set and comes up as nil so I cannot set the level.